# bad operand types for binary operator '||'

Tags: java

I am not sure what I am doing wrong in this code. I want this method to return valid when the user prompts the number in either of these two formats XXX-XX-XXXX or XXXXXXXXX. Can someone help me please? Thanks!

```
public class SSNValidator {
public static boolean isValidSSN(String ssn) {
    return ssn.matches(("[1-9]\\d{2}-[1-9]\\d{1}-\\d{4}") || ("[1-9]\\d{9}")) ;
}
```

Comment: `("[1-9]\\d{2}-[1-9]\\d{1}-\\d{4}") || ("[1-9]\\d{9}")` evals to `true`, since it's a logical or. You probably are either looking for the bitwise or or, eventually, which makes significantly more sense, you should perform an or inside your regex or make two regexes.

Comment: Your using an `||` on the strings itself which will lead to `ssn.matches(true)` which likely isn't what you want. Instead do it on two `.matches` like `ssn.matches(str1) || ssn.matches(str2)`. Or you could use a regex OR and combine them `(exp1) | (exp2)`.

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding how `||` works. This is what you're looking for:

```
return ssn.matches("[1-9]\\d{2}-[1-9]\\d{1}-\\d{4}") || ssn.matches("[1-9]\\d{9}");
```

Read up on the basics about logical operators.

Comment: Hi Mate, I just tried the code but it doesn't return True when I typed in 523562712. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: @BrandonRussk Your regexes are only allowing `1` to `9`, not including `0`. Also don't immediately change your comment to make others irreverent or misleading...

Comment: Yeah I know. I changed it to 0-9 in my javascript but it still doesn't work.

Comment: `[1-9]\d{9}` expects 10 digits in total

Answer (score -2):

The regex OR operator is just a single |, so your refer expression should be

```
"[1-9]\\d{2}-[1-9]\\d{1}-\\d{4}") | ("[1-9]\\d{9}"
```

Comment: Do you mean: `([1-9]\\d{2}-[1-9]\\d{1}-\\d{4}) | ([1-9]\\d{9})`?

Comment: In OP's example, the `||` operator is outside the regex strings, not part of the regex

Comment: Ah yes missed that @SpencerWieczorek.